# Streaming Data Generator

Tags: java, scala, sockets, streaming, apache-spark

I'm trying to implement a type of streaming data generator to be used as source data for a streaming application developed with Apache Spark Streaming.

The data can be sent to a network socket. I have some synthetic files that contain several words. Then, I'll need to send each word of these files to a socket and to determine each word as 100 byte input register.

First, I did a script like this:

```
COUNTER=1
while [ $COUNTER -lt 101 ]; do 
    echo $COUNTER
    cat file_$COUNTER | nc -l 2211
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1   
done
```

But in this case I couldn't control the byte size and other factors. I wanted something a little more useful developed in Java/Scala.

Can anyone suggest something to start?

Comment: What byte size do you want to control?  The size of the file_$COUNTER file or what?   Using various shell tricks you can control this - not sure why you want java or scala.  This kind of short shell utility might be more easily suited to shell, python, or perl.